# Qt UDP read error

Tags: c++, qt, networking, udp, qt5

I try to write a little client-server program. A client should detect all servers running in the same LAN. I tried to implement a UDP-Broadcast with qt but my read function returns -1 all the time. If I call the `dataAvailable()`-function on the socket, it says that 4 bytes are available to read, but for some reason it fails to read them.

For now I'm trying to receive the broadcast on the same machine and in the same program

Here's my main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QString>
#include <QThread>

#include "../include/network.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace network;

int main () {
    Network *n = new Network ();
    n->broadcast("test");

    if (n->dataAvailable()) {
        cout << "Data available: ";
        cout << n->getData().toStdString() << std::endl;
    } else {
        cout << "No data" << endl;
    }
    delete n;
}
```

and my Network-class:

```
#ifndef NETWORK
#define NETWORK

#include <QObject>
#include <QUdpSocket>
#include <iostream>

namespace network {

    class Network : public QObject {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        const static int BROADCAST_PORT = 52433;

        explicit Network(QObject *parent = 0) {
            socket = new QUdpSocket ();
            socket->bind (QHostAddress::Any, BROADCAST_PORT);
        }

        ~Network () {
            delete socket;
        }

        bool dataAvailable () {
            return socket->hasPendingDatagrams();
        }

        QString getData () {
            if (!dataAvailable()) {
                return "";
            }
            char *data = 0;
            std::cout << socket->pendingDatagramSize() << std::endl;
            std::cout << QString("recv: %1")
                    .arg(socket->readDatagram(data,
                                 socket->pendingDatagramSize())).toStdString();
            return QString(data);
        }

        void broadcast(QString data) {
            QUdpSocket *broadcast = new QUdpSocket ();
            broadcast->connectToHost(QHostAddress::Broadcast, BROADCAST_PORT);
            std::cout << broadcast->write(data.toStdString().c_str())
                      << std::endl << std::endl;
            delete broadcast;
        }

    private:
        QUdpSocket *socket;
    };

}

#endif // NETWORK
```

the Output is the following:

```
4

Data available: 4
recv -1
```

Which means

1. 4 Bytes are sent from the broadcast
2. the socket detects that 4 bytes are available
3. the attempt to read the 4 bytes fails
4. the QString returned by `getData()` is empty

Unfortunately I could not find any possibility to get more information on the error

Comment: I don't know how Qt works, but ordinarily when a system call like [`recvfrom(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom) fails, it returns `-1` and sets the error code to the global variable `errno`.  If you checked the value of `errno`, you'd probably see that `errno` was `EFAULT`, indicating that you passed an invalid address to the kernel, assuming that `errno` doesn't get reset by Qt.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't know about `errno` :( can you recommand a good read to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definitely need to allocate memory for reading datagram. Now you try to write it to null pointer.

```
// char *data = 0;
std::cout << socket->pendingDatagramSize() << std::endl;
QVector<char> buffer(socket->pendingDatagramSize()); // create buffer
std::cout << QString("recv: %1")
        .arg(socket->readDatagram(buffer.data(),
                socket->pendingDatagramSize())).toStdString();
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem. I thought the function allocates the memory it needs by itself and the char* pointer is set to the address the memory is.
But this way the size-parameter makes sense, too.